# Does a full set of legible structural engineering drawings for the Hughes H-4 Hercules still exist?

Tags: aircraft-design, aviation-history

I am not looking for unreadable images or pictures of images, but a fully legible copy or print.

I have found a reference to a set of drawings at UNLV however no contact info nor a department to contact

Comment: Could the Smithsonian keep something like this?

Comment: I would think so but no. Also I would think there would be copies in the library of congress since they investigated it but no on that as well

Comment: I would contact the Evergreen Air and Space Museum in McMinville, OR. They currently have the actual H-4 prototype and their curators may be able to help.

Comment: According to Wikipedia the aircraft division was sold to Raytheon. Maybe they have retained the original blue prints of the aircrafts...

Answer (score 1):

Contact the Evergreen Aviation & Space Museum and speak with a Docent.
https://goo.gl/maps/EDfpig8RVzSj85U28

Comment: Wonder if the Hughes H-4 in Microsoft Flight Simulator was modeled based on original drawings, or just ad-hoc measurements, photos and LIDAR scans of the preserved aircraft.